# Drag the certain object on picbox doesn't drag the all image on it

Tags: vb6, picturebox

I want to ask if it is possible to drag the image on picbox, when mouse cursor point to the certain object, so when I select the X-textbox, y-textbox, and select pin text
it will displat accourding my coordinate n pin number i selected.

But I want to drag them on picturebox. When mouse cursor touches that certain IC image, it can be drag. But not all the image on picbox drag together.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

My full code below:

```
Option Explicit
Private mPic        As Picture
Private mPicWidth   As Single
Private mPicHeight  As Single
Private mCurrentX   As Single
Private mCurrentY   As Single
Private mLeft       As Single
Private mTop        As Single

Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Call draw_ic(Val(Text5), Val(Text6), Val(Text7))
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Picture1.AutoRedraw = True
    Set mPic = Picture1.Image
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As    Single)
    mPicWidth = Me.ScaleX(mPic.Width, vbHimetric, Picture1.ScaleMode)
    mPicHeight = Me.ScaleY(mPic.Height, vbHimetric, Picture1.ScaleMode)
    ShowPictureAtPosition mLeft, mTop
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 0 Then
        mCurrentX = X
        mCurrentY = Y
    ElseIf Button = vbLeftButton Then
        ShowPictureAtPosition X + mLeft - mCurrentX, Y + mTop - mCurrentY
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    mLeft = X + mLeft - mCurrentX: mTop = Y + mTop - mCurrentY
End Sub

Private Sub ShowPictureAtPosition(pX As Single, pY As Single)
    With Picture1    
        .Cls
       .PaintPicture mPic, pX + 1, pY + 1, mPicWidth, mPicHeight    
    End With
End Sub

Function draw_ic(X, Y, pincount)
    If pincount = 8 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y)-(X + 120, Y + 48), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y)-(X + 24, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y)-(X + 50, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y)-(X + 76, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y)-(X + 102, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 48)-(X + 24, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 48)-(X + 50, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 48)-(X + 76, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 48)-(X + 102, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
    ElseIf pincount = 12 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y)-(X + 158, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y)-(X + 16, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 32, Y)-(X + 40, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 56, Y)-(X + 64, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 80, Y)-(X + 88, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 104, Y)-(X + 112, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 128, Y)-(X + 136, Y - 8), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 64)-(X + 16, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 32, Y + 64)-(X + 40, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 56, Y + 64)-(X + 64, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 80, Y + 64)-(X + 88, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 104, Y + 64)-(X + 112, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 128, Y + 64)-(X + 136, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
    ElseIf pincount = 16 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y)-(X + 222, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y)-(X + 24, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y)-(X + 50, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y)-(X + 76, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y)-(X + 102, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 112, Y)-(X + 128, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 138, Y)-(X + 154, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 164, Y)-(X + 180, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 190, Y)-(X + 206, Y - 16), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 72)-(X + 24, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 72)-(X + 50, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 72)-(X + 76, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 72)-(X + 102, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 112, Y + 72)-(X + 128, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 138, Y + 72)-(X + 154, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 164, Y + 72)-(X + 180, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 190, Y + 72)-(X + 206, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting project !

Consider the coordinates of the following image.

[image]

Every time that you create a new IC, if you save its top-left and bottom-right coordinates, it will help you to determine when the mouse pointer reaches its area by using the following code.

```
Private Function MouseCursorInsideRectangle(topLeftX As Integer, topLeftY As Integer, bottomRightX As Integer, bottomRightY As Integer, mouseX As Integer, mouseY As Integer) As Boolean
    If mouseX >= topLeftX And mouseX <= bottomRightX And mouseY >= topLeftY And mouseY <= bottomRightY Then
        MouseCursorInsideRectangle = True
    Else
        MouseCursorInsideRectangle = False
    End If
End Function
```

This will resolve the issue of overlapping ICs, since you can check the coordinate of the IC that you want to draw and disallow the drawing, if it's over another one.

To solve the issue of moving only a certain IC and not the whole PictureBox image, you can clear the image when a drag event is in progress and draw all the ICs again (by using the coordinates that you saved during their creation) through iteration.

(Although it is not in your requirements, consider also saving the coordinates of the pins of each IC, so you can draw lines between ICs in the future).

**EDIT**

Try the below code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Type ICData
    topLeftX As Integer
    topLeftY As Integer
    bottomRightX As Integer
    bottomRightY As Integer
    pinCount As Integer
End Type

Dim ICs() As ICData
Dim ICsIndex As Integer
Dim DraggedICIndex As Integer
Dim Xdifference As Integer
Dim Ydifference As Integer

Dim InitialX As Integer
Dim InitialY As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ICsIndex = -1
    DraggedICIndex = -1
    Picture1.ScaleMode = 3
    Picture1.AutoRedraw = True
End Sub

Private Sub Command5_Click()        
    Call save_ic(Val(text5), Val(text6), Val(text7))
    Call draw_ics(-1)
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    DraggedICIndex = GetICIndex(CSng(X), CSng(Y))

    If DraggedICIndex > -1 Then
        InitialX = ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftX
        InitialY = ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftY

        Xdifference = Abs(X - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftX)
        Ydifference = Abs(Y - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftY)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = vbLeftButton And DraggedICIndex > -1 Then
        Picture1.Cls

        Call draw_ics(DraggedICIndex)
        Call draw_ic(X - Xdifference, Y - Ydifference, ICs(DraggedICIndex).pinCount)

        Dim ICWidth As Integer
        Dim ICHeight As Integer

        ICWidth = ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightX - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftX
        ICHeight = ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightY - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftY
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If DraggedICIndex > -1 Then
        Dim ICWidth As Integer
        Dim ICHeight As Integer

        ICWidth = ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightX - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftX
        ICHeight = ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightY - ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftY

        ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftX = X - Xdifference
        ICs(DraggedICIndex).topLeftY = Y - Ydifference
        ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightX = ICWidth + X - Xdifference
        ICs(DraggedICIndex).bottomRightY = ICHeight + Y - Ydifference
    End If
End Sub

Private Function MouseCursorInsideRectangle(location As ICData, mouseX As Integer, mouseY As Integer) As Boolean
    If mouseX >= location.topLeftX And mouseX <= location.bottomRightX And mouseY >= location.topLeftY And mouseY <= location.bottomRightY Then
        MouseCursorInsideRectangle = True
    Else
        MouseCursorInsideRectangle = False
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetICIndex(mouseX As Integer, mouseY As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To ICsIndex
        If MouseCursorInsideRectangle(ICs(i), mouseX, mouseY) = True Then
            GetICIndex = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    GetICIndex = -1
End Function

Sub save_ic(X, Y, pinCount)
    If pinCount = 8 Then
        ICsIndex = ICsIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve ICs(ICsIndex)

        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftX = X
        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftY = Y
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightX = X + 120
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightY = Y + 80
        ICs(ICsIndex).pinCount = pinCount
    ElseIf pinCount = 12 Then
        ICsIndex = ICsIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve ICs(ICsIndex)

        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftX = X
        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftY = Y
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightX = X + 158
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightY = Y + 80
        ICs(ICsIndex).pinCount = pinCount
    ElseIf pinCount = 16 Then
        ICsIndex = ICsIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve ICs(ICsIndex)

        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftX = X
        ICs(ICsIndex).topLeftY = Y
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightX = X + 222
        ICs(ICsIndex).bottomRightY = Y + 104
        ICs(ICsIndex).pinCount = pinCount
    End If
End Sub

Sub draw_ic(X, Y, pinCount)
    If pinCount = 8 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y + 16)-(X + 120, Y + 64), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 16)-(X + 24, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 16)-(X + 50, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 16)-(X + 76, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 16)-(X + 102, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 64)-(X + 24, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 64)-(X + 50, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 64)-(X + 76, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 64)-(X + 102, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
    ElseIf pinCount = 12 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y + 8)-(X + 158, Y + 72), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 8)-(X + 16, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 32, Y + 8)-(X + 40, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 56, Y + 8)-(X + 64, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 80, Y + 8)-(X + 88, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 104, Y + 8)-(X + 112, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 128, Y + 8)-(X + 136, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 72)-(X + 16, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 32, Y + 72)-(X + 40, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 56, Y + 72)-(X + 64, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 80, Y + 72)-(X + 88, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 104, Y + 72)-(X + 112, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 128, Y + 72)-(X + 136, Y + 80), vbBlack, B
    ElseIf pinCount = 16 Then
        Picture1.Line (X, Y + 16)-(X + 222, Y + 88), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 16)-(X + 24, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 16)-(X + 50, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 16)-(X + 76, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 16)-(X + 102, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 112, Y + 16)-(X + 128, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 138, Y + 16)-(X + 154, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 164, Y + 16)-(X + 180, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 190, Y + 16)-(X + 206, Y), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 8, Y + 88)-(X + 24, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 34, Y + 88)-(X + 50, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 60, Y + 88)-(X + 76, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 86, Y + 88)-(X + 102, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 112, Y + 88)-(X + 128, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 138, Y + 88)-(X + 154, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 164, Y + 88)-(X + 180, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
        Picture1.Line (X + 190, Y + 88)-(X + 206, Y + 104), vbBlack, B
    End If
End Sub

Sub draw_ics(exceptICIndex As Integer)
    If ICsIndex > -1 Then
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To ICsIndex
            If i <> exceptICIndex Then
                Call draw_ic(ICs(i).topLeftX, ICs(i).topLeftY, ICs(i).pinCount)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I leave the IC overlap implementation on you :).

Comment: Thx David. very useful but this function i need call at which part adn how i save its top-left and bottom-right coordinates. Quiet confiusing. Sry , im totally a newbie in this VB6.
 THx in advance

Comment: Dear @David,
izit u can edit my code and show me? im really frustrated after try this whole day. still cannot move the certain IC.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Dear Mr David, IT worked..need so many function cover it up. Nowander me as a beginner cant think that.. Thx u very much n nice to meet u.
Overlap implementation i think i can solve it based on these concept.